# Use of ngDisabled in ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Looking at the template for ui-bootstrap pagination, I do not understand the use of `ngDisabled` in `ng-class`. I am reaching out for some help in understanding this.

I looked in the `'PaginationController'` and ngDisabled is not a scope property, does it refer to the ng-disabled directive?

```
<ul class="pagination"> 
  <li ng-if="::boundaryLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-first"><a href ng-click="selectPage(1, $event)">{{::getText('first')}}</a></li> 
  <li ng-if="::directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-prev"><a href ng-click="selectPage(page - 1, $event)">{{::getText('previous')}}</a></li> 
  <li ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index" ng-class="{active: page.active,disabled: ngDisabled&&!page.active}" class="pagination-page"><a href ng-click="selectPage(page.number, $event)">{{page.text}}</a></li> 
  <li ng-if="::directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-next"><a href ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)">{{::getText('next')}}</a></li> 
  <li ng-if="::boundaryLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-last"><a href ng-click="selectPage(totalPages, $event)">{{::getText('last')}}</a></li> 
</ul>
```

EDIT

As Shamal pointed out, ngDisabled is on the scope of the pagination directive:

```
.directive('pagination', ['$parse', 'paginationConfig',   function($parse, paginationConfig) {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      totalItems: '=',
      firstText: '@',
      previousText: '@',
      nextText: '@',
      lastText: '@',
      ngDisabled:'='
    },
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ngDisabled is from the directive.

If ng-disabled is set to true in the directive then disabled class would apply if noPrevious() returns false. You can conditionally apply the class to li.

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngDisabled: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
  };
});
```

---

```
<my-directive ng-disabled="true"></my-directive>
```

Comment: I tried it in a plunker, set ng-disabled="true", noPrevious() returns false for pages>1, but "Previous" is not disabled. Is this what you meant? http://plnkr.co/edit/sN2xLo?p=preview

Comment: Yes ngDisabled is on the pagination directive scope, you are right. I missed it before.

Comment: Hmmm that's weird. Check this http://plnkr.co/edit/8TaQkapZRCbD7fYNORKy?p=preview

Comment: It is a version issue

Comment: yes, ng-disabled works for the latest version angular-bootstrap#0.13.3.